# Unable to call a template member function of a template class from another template class

Tags: c++, templates

I'm getting compiler errors when attempting to access a template member function of a template class from within another template class. A function call to `getSubmatrix` results in the compiler warnings, "expression result unused", about the parameters `(0, 0)`, finally failing with the compiler error "reference to non-static member function must be called".

The matrix class:

```
template <std::size_t m, std::size_t n, typename T, std::size_t rowPadding = 0>
class Matrix
{
public:
    ...

    template <std::size_t p, std::size_t q>
    Matrix<p, q, T, n - q>& getSubmatrix(std::size_t column, std::size_t row)
    {
        ...
    }
};
```

The transform class:

```
template <typename T>
class Transform
{
public:
    ...

    Matrix<4, 4, T> matrix() const
    {
        ...

        Matrix<4, 4, T> result;
        result.getSubmatrix<3, 3>(0, 0) = Matrix<3, 3, T>();

        ...
    }
};
```

Note that changing the matrix type to `Matrix<4, 4, float>` rather than `Matrix<4, 4, T>` will result in valid compilation. The compiler is clang 4.0 and the language version is C++11.

Comment: Thank you very much for this entry, this one was extremely tricky to infer from Clang error message indeed.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should add keyword `template`:

```
result.template getSubmatrix<3, 3>(0, 0) = Matrix<3, 3, T>();
//     ^^^^^^^^
```

Without it, compiler will think that `<` is a comparison operator.

PS. In that case, g++ produces a little more understandable error:

> error: invalid operands of types `<unresolved overloaded function type>` and `int` to binary `operator<`

Comment: <sarcasm> Gosh, C++ template syntax is so intuitive. </sarcasm>

Comment: It's almost as someone invented template syntax way later in making the language specs... :P

Comment: Microsoft C++ compiler does the "right thing" in this case, even if it technically shouldn't. Bookmarked this answer because it bites me on the arse every few months. Thanks @awesoon!